# Growing a Forest by 1 node corrupts PST barcode picture

Tags: forest, auto-pst-pdf, pst-barcode

Working on a different problem, I realized that QR Codes worked or did not work in the documents, different only in their Forest trees.

It appears that if the 2nd last node (Child10) of Forest is un-commented in the MWE below, the QR Code becomes corrupt (top portion wiped out). If the last node (Child11) is un-commented, then QR Code disappears.

Replacing a PST Barcode QR Code with a regular JPG image produces correct rendering, i.e. PST barcode is the root cause.

As the Forest is machine-generated and can be of any size, it has to be in a standalone class. Thus I cannot hardcode any sizes, including paper size and this will have to be printed on multiple pages.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l r}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Title\\
Text\\
\end{tabular} &

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{pspicture}(1.02in,1.02in)
    \psbarcode{http://localhost/Intranet/OrgChart.aspx?id=10509110}{version=5}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{adjustbox} \\
 & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\footnotesize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where n children=0{
        child anchor=west,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        draw=red,for parent={
            parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge, draw=blue          
        }
    }{}
}
    [Parent,name=Parent
        [Child1
            [,phantom]
            [Child11]
            [Child12]
        ]
        [Child3
            [,phantom]
            [Child31]
            [Child32]
        ]
        [Child4
            [,phantom]
            [Child41]
            [Child42]
        ]
        [Child5
            [,phantom]
            [Child51]
            [Child52]
        ]
        [Child6
            [,phantom]
            [Child61]
            [Child62]
        ]
        [Child7
            [,phantom]
            [Child71]
            [Child72]
        ]
        [Child8
            [,phantom]
            [Child81]
            [Child82]
        ]
        [Child9
            [,phantom]
            [Child91]
            [Child92]
        ]
%       [Child10
%           [,phantom]
%           [Child101]
%           [Child102]
%       ]
%       [Child11
%           [,phantom]
%           [Child111]
%           [Child112]
%       ]
    ]
\end{forest}
} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{
\begin{tiny}Copyright \textcopyright{} Myself, 2014\end{tiny}
}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works without a problem: run `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{forest}
\else
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
\fi
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} l}
Title\\
Text
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\begin{pspicture}[pgffunctions](1.02in,1.02in)
    \psbarcode{http://localhost/Intranet/OrgChart.aspx?id=10509110}{version=5}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}}
\\
\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\footnotesize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where n children=0{
        child anchor=west,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        draw=red,for parent={
            parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge, draw=blue          
        }
    }{}
}
    [Parent,name=Parent
        [Child1
            [,phantom]
            [Child11]
            [Child12]
        ]
        [Child3
            [,phantom]
            [Child31]
            [Child32]
        ]
        [Child4
            [,phantom]
            [Child41]
            [Child42]
        ]
        [Child5
            [,phantom]
            [Child51]
            [Child52]
        ]
        [Child6
            [,phantom]
            [Child61]
            [Child62]
        ]
        [Child7
            [,phantom]
            [Child71]
            [Child72]
        ]
        [Child8
            [,phantom]
            [Child81]
            [Child82]
        ]
        [Child9
            [,phantom]
            [Child91]
            [Child92]
        ]
       [Child10
           [,phantom]
           [Child101]
           [Child102]
       ]
       [Child11
           [,phantom]
           [Child111]
           [Child112]
       ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\\
{\tiny Copyright \textcopyright{} Myself, 2014}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not going to work as this has to be a standalone class. The forest size is arbitrary. No sizes can be hardcoded at all.

Comment: Edited the question to indicate standalone is a requirement.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Do you understand what exactly corrupts PST barcode and how did you fix that? If I knew what you did, I could implement that in my original template, as I have to keep the top of title aligned with the top of QR code.

Comment: It is a problem with pgf/tikZ, not pst-barcode. They changed a lot of internal code.

Comment: But isn't PST barcode externalized? Should it be affected by Tikz? If that's the case, I can probably generate bar code separately and simply include its PDF

Comment: Sure, but with your code `forest` was also loaded when the barcode (`pst-barcode`) was created. With `\ifpdf ...\fi` it will be prevented.

Comment: Brilliant! Just that if/else solves everything in itself!